# Chrome magnet links open up Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, bittorrent, magnet

When I try to download a torrent using a magnet link it first opens firefox, and then it opens transmission. Is there a way to fix this? I want chrome to directly open up transmission, not transferring it to firefox.

Comment: Try making Chrome the [default browser](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95417) again.

Comment: Chrome is my default browser right now.

Answer (score 0):

It’s likely that magnet file-type registration has been changed and Chrome’s default-detection algorithm does not check that. Set Firefox (or another browser) as your default browser, then [set Chrome](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95417) back as the default browser again to have Chrome re-register its file-types, including magnet links.